# SQL best practice/performance when inserting into a table. To use a temp table or not

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a select query that's come about from me trying to remove while loops from an existing query that was far too slow. As it stands I first select into a temp table.

Then from that temp table I insert into the final table using the values from the temp table.

Below is a simplified example of the flow of my query

```sql
select 
    b.BookId, 
    b.BookDescription, 
    a.Name,
    a.BirthDate, 
    a.CountryOfOrigin,
into #tempTable
from library.Book b
left join authors.Authors a
on a.AuthorId = b.AuthorId

insert into bookStore.BookStore
    ([BookStoreEntryId]
    [BookId],
    [BookDescription],
    [Author],
    [AuthorBirthdate],
    [AuthorCountryOfOrigin])
select 
    NEWID(),
    t.BookId,
    t.BookDescription,
    t.Name,
    t.Birthdate,
    t.CountryOfOrigin

from #tempTable t

drop table #tempTable
```

Would it be better to move the select statement at the start, to below so that its incorporated into the insert statement, removing the need for the temp table?

Comment: I don't think you need temp table here

Comment: @T.S. what would you say is a good reason to make use of a temp table?

Comment: Why do you think the temporary table would improve the performance, when you're forcing the RDBMS to write the data to `tempdb` and then again to the database. If anything, removing the `DISTINCT` is going to be far more performant.

Comment: I suggest you think carefully about whether you need `DISTINCT`, and about what indexes you have on the table. It looks to me that the temp table is just a sticking plaster to cover bigger problems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no advantage at all to having a temporary table in this case.  Just use the select query directly.

Sometimes, temporary tables can improve performance.  One method is that a real table has real statistics (notably the number of rows).  The optimizer can use that information for better execution plans.

Temporary tables can also improve performance if they explicit have an index on them.

However, they incur overhead of writing the table.

In this case, you just get all the overhead and there should be no benefit.

Actually, I could imagine one benefit under one circumstance.  If the query took a long time to run -- say because the join required a nested loops join with no indexes -- then the destination table would be saved from locking and contention until all the rows are available for insert.  That would be an unusual case, though.

Comment: There's a good chance the top select on the real query could take well over an hour. The original query, before I made the changes was taking roughly 6 hours because of nested while loops and a relatively large dataset.

In this time there are other processes that could be making use of the destination table.

So if I'm not mistaken my situation falls within your unusual case.

Comment: @DamianJacobs . . . Quite possibly "yes".  it seems unlikely that any of your tables are called "books" or "authors", though.

Comment: Books yes, authors no. Actual query deals with finance and is a bit more involved.
Thank you very much for your unusual circumstance. I appreciate the thought that went into adding that into your answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do in 1 step

```sql
insert into bookStore.BookStore
    ( /* [BookStoreEntryId] <-- assuming this is auto id*/ 
    [BookId],
    [BookDescription],
    [Author],
    [AuthorBirthdate],
    [AuthorCountryOfOrigin])
SELECT distinct 
    b.BookId, 
    b.BookDescription, 
    a.Name,
    a.BirthDate, 
    a.CountryOfOrigin,
from library.Book b
left join authors.Authors a
on a.AuthorId = b.AuthorId
```

your performance will depend on number of indexes in the target table. More indexes - slower insert. May be worth to disable them during insert and then rebuild them after the insert is completed